# Pandas - Float to Date conversion YYYY-MM

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a Column 'Date' which has values in the form YYYYMM,
The Column date is of type float.

I wish to convert it in to date type as YYYY-MM.

When I try the below, it gives the error float is not sliceable.

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%Y%m').dt.strftime('%Y%m')
```

Input Data

```
 Date(Float)
    201101.0
    201812.0
```

Output Required

```
Date(Date Type)
2011-01
2018-12
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use

```
In [26]: pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%Y%m.0').dt.strftime('%Y-%m')
Out[26]:
0    2011-01
1    2018-12
Name: Date, dtype: object
```

Use `pd.to_datetime(...,  errors='coerce')` to replace incomptabile values as `NaT`

Comment: @Zero It worked, It tried the same for 2 columns, when I try to subtract those columns, it throws error.

Comment: @TomJMuthirenthi please accept the current answer and ask a new question for your new problem...

Comment: @IanS https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49173429/month-difference-yyyymm-pandas. New question