# MonthEnd object result in <11 * MonthEnds> instead of number

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

In my pandas dataframe I want to find the difference between dates in months. The function `.dt.to_period('M')` results in a MonthEnd object like `<11 * MonthEnds>` instead of the month number.

I tried to change the column type with `pd.to_numeric()` and to remove the letters with `re.sub("[^0-9]", "", 'blablabla123bla')`. Both do not work on a `MonthEnd` object.

```
df['duration_dataset'] = df['date_1'].dt.to_period('M') - df['date_2'].dt.to_period('M')
```

I expected 11, but the output is `<11 * MonthEnds>`.

Here is a minimum dataframe

```
d = {'date_1': ['2018-03-31','2018-09-30'], 'date_2': ['2017-12-31','2017-12-31']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

df['date_1'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date_1'], format='%Y-%m-%d')
df['date_2'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date_2'], format='%Y-%m-%d')

df['duration_dataset'] = df['date_1'].dt.to_period('M') - df['date_2'].dt.to_period('M')

df
```

Comment: I find that behavior, pandas 0.24.0

Comment: You appear to have [`pd.MonthEnd()` objects](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.tseries.offsets.MonthEnd.html#pandas.tseries.offsets.MonthEnd), so these are [date offsets](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#dateoffset-objects).

Comment: Can you please create a minimal dataframe that reproduces the issue? Include code to produce a frame with a few rows to show how the `MonthEnd` instances are created, so we can help correct that and get you the integer month count instead.

Comment: Ah, I was testing with Pandas 0.23.4, upgrading now.

Comment: I have Pandas version 0.24.0

Comment: You could try to access the `MonthEnd` object by using `<object>.__dict__['n']`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is [new behaviour in Pandas 0.24](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew/v0.24.0.html#period-subtraction), where subtracting `Period()` objects give you a [`DateOffset` subclass](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.tseries.offsets.DateOffset.html).

You can get the numeric value from the `DateOffset.n` attribute:

```
from operator import attrgetter

df['duration_dataset'] = (
    df['date_1'].dt.to_period('M') -
    df['date_2'].dt.to_period('M')).apply(attrgetter('n'))
```

This produces

```
      date_1     date_2  duration_dataset
0 2018-03-31 2017-12-31                 3
1 2018-09-30 2017-12-31                 9
```

for your sample dataframe.

Rather than convert your dates to periods, you could instead convert them to a month count since the year 0, then subtract those numbers:

```
df['duration_dataset'] = (
    df['date_1'].dt.year * 12 + df['date_1'].dt.month - 1 -
    (df['date_2'].dt.year * 12 + df['date_2'].dt.month - 1)
)
```

which can be simplified to

```
df['duration_dataset'] = (
    12 * (df['date_1'].dt.year - df['date_2'].dt.year) +
    df['date_1'].dt.month - df['date_2'].dt.month
)
```

Comment: I've wasted about four hours of my life trying to figure this out. Thank you SOO much!

Comment: There's no need to subtract by `1` when you do `df['duration_dataset'] = (
    df['date_1'].dt.year * 12 + df['date_1'].dt.month - 1 -
    (df['date_2'].dt.year * 12 + df['date_2'].dt.month - 1)
)`, right?

Comment: @titusAdam: in the direct subtraction here, the `-1` on both side of the equation can be eliminated, yes: `df['date_1'].dt.year * 12 + df['date_1'].dt.month - df['date_2'].dt.year * 12 - df['date_2'].dt.month`.

Answer (score 8):

You can also coerce `Period` to `int` using `astype('int')` and directly take the difference:

```
df['duration_dataset'] = df['date_1'].dt.to_period('M').astype('int') - df['date_2'].dt.to_period('M').astype('int')
```

It seems to be faster.

Comment: This now yields "FutureWarning: The behavior of .astype from period[M] to int32 is deprecated. In a future version, this astype will return exactly the specified dtype instead of int64, and will raise if that conversion overflows."  

Making something like this necessary:

  df['duration_dataset'] = (df['date_1'].dt.to_period('M') - df['date_2'].dt.to_period('M')).apply(lambda x: x.n)

Comment: Which version of pandas is that?

Comment: 1.5.0 and 1.5.1

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative to access n attribute for the accepted answer for pandas 0.24 is

```
df['duration_dataset'].apply(lambda x: x.n)
```

Comment: This has problems with NaT

Comment: @David Davó

`if pd.notnull(x) else x` can be added.

`df['duration_dataset'].apply(lambda x: x.n if pd.notnull(x) else x)`

And if someone wanted to take the column from an Object to Int type 
`df['duration_dataset'].apply(lambda x: x.n if pd.notnull(x) else x).fillna(np.nan).astype('Int64')`